# Youtube player cost for android

Tags: youtube-data-api

I want to add Youtube Player for android to play youtube video, so I want to know following things.

1. What is the daily limit of videos I can play.
2. If playing videos is paid then what is the cost of it.

I have gone different places but not received any exact answers for my questions, my requirement is only to play youtube videos in my android app
with the help of Youtubeplayer library.

Comment: Does this help? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota

Comment: Also, I don't think this API can be used to watch video. It is for everything else. Maybe https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference is what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks, I have gone through the link you shared above but not sure about the prices for taking more quota, so if any of you have the list of prices where i can clarify it please share.

Comment: Looks like they would answer your question in due time: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support